# JavaScript switch function

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I am trying to get this code running but it gives me an error saying "unexpected end of input". Would you please help? Thanks in advance.

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
switch (movie) {
case "Toy Story 2":
    return "Great story. Mean prospector.";
    break;
case "Finding Nemo" :
    return "Cool animation, and funny turtles.";
    break;
case "The Lion King" :
    return "Great songs.";
    break;
default : 
    return "I dont know!"; 
    break;
};
```

Comment: You need a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: you also don't need a break statement at the end, as it is the end of the switch anyway

Comment: function needs a } at the end

Comment: ... you also need a good IDE that would highlight such syntax errors.

Comment: Also note that if this is going to be a big list, you want to store the answers in something like JSON, not in a ridiculously long switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you're missing the closing brace on your function:

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    switch (movie) {
    case "Toy Story 2":
        return "Great story. Mean prospector.";
        break;
    case "Finding Nemo" :
        return "Cool animation, and funny turtles.";
        break;
    case "The Lion King" :
        return "Great songs.";
        break;
    default : 
        return "I dont know!"; 
        break;
    };
};  // <-- here
```

Also note that it makes no sense to have a `break` after a `return` or a semicolon at the end of a `switch` block. You can reduce the above to this:

```
var getReview = function (movie) {
    switch (movie) {
    case "Toy Story 2":
        return "Great story. Mean prospector.";
    case "Finding Nemo" :
        return "Cool animation, and funny turtles.";
    case "The Lion King" :
        return "Great songs.";
    default : 
        return "I dont know!"; 
    }
};
```

Comment: oh man, thank you ! I must be too tired today. I appreciate it!